# Timers and variables in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timer, boolean

I have a class with a timer. The timer starts in the new method. The method associated with the timer is checkMatch() but checkTimer() ensures the parameters are met to start the timer. They are met and the timer starts. The method checkMatch() is currently rewritten to only execute once since I know it keeps repeating itself. The only place to change the boolean variable oneTime is located inside of checkMatch(). I included the autoLoad() function just in case it is needed. Whenever I launch this class, the forms associated with the other methods not listed will pop up and instantly go away. The console shows that checkMatch() is being called regularly (which it should), but that the variable oneTime remains True each time it is called. The timer is started at the end of the autoLoad() method. I know all the methods in autoLoad() are being called and executed.

Since oneTime is showing as True constantly in the console, I am assuming I have a conception issue somewhere. Why is oneTime true each time checkMatch() is called?

```
  ' a user is required for this class
    Public Sub New(ByVal my_user As RGOUser)
        My.Settings.selected_summoner = "huge legend"
        My.Settings.Region = "na1"
        My.Settings.Save()
        myUser = my_user
        AddHandler tmr.Elapsed, AddressOf checkMatch
        checkTimer()
    End Sub

Public Sub checkMatch()
        Console.WriteLine(Me.GetType.ToString() + "||" + System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine(oneTime)
        Try
            Dim psList() As Process = Process.GetProcesses()
            For Each p As Process In psList
                '    If strLeagueProcessName = p.ProcessName) And Not boolInGame Then
                ' remove later and replace with commented line
                If oneTime Then
                    Console.WriteLine("checkMatch Success.")
                    boolInGame = True
                    oneTime = False
                    tmr.Interval = timerInsideMatch
                    tmr.Stop()
                    Try
                        autoLoad()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try
                    Return
                Else
                    Return
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("checkMatch Failure. " + ex.Message)
        End Try
        boolInGame = False
        tmr.Interval = timerOutsideMatch
    End Sub

Private Sub autoLoad()
        Console.WriteLine(Me.GetType.ToString() + "||" + System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.ToString())
        If searchMatch() Then
            Dim x As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf loadConfiguration)
            Dim y As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf loadMatch)
            Dim z As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf launchMinimap)
            If My.Settings.configuration_auto_load Then
                Try
                    x.Start()
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
            End If
            If My.Settings.loadMatch Then
                Try
                    y.Start()
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
            End If
            If My.Settings.launchMinimap Then
                Try
                    z.Start()
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
            End If
            x.Join()
            y.Join()
            z.Join()
            tmr.Start()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Its probably not the timer(s) but the threads (if I understood correctly)...or it could be the empty Catch blocks.  Are there multiple instances of the class each running those threads?

Comment: You aren't showing how you initialized oneTime. Did you assign a value on declaration? If you did and that value is set to True then put a break point on oneTime = False in sub checkMatch. Do you get a hit on this break point? I suspect you are changing the value of oneTime somewhere else.

Comment: There actually was another instance that my partner must have added. Of course, now the forms still display for a split second and then seemingly vanish. It did solve half the problem though, I should add the ways to write any errors to console to find the next problem. I just knew it wouldn't help with the first problem since the console was displaying strange values.

Comment: @Chillzy Sorry, it is a global variable declared true at the top of the instance. I didn't want to add 200 lines but it seems Plutonix solved the issue with the variable not updating correctly, I just have to find out why the forms are not displaying since I know they do manually (and they display correctly).

Comment: right click on oneTime and click Find all references. put a break point on each of them

Comment: @Plutonix that was an amazing catch. How does the double classes keep the variable from changing to false? I would have never even thought to look.

Comment: @chillzy, Plutonix figured out the boolean variable issue. The two classes caused something strange. The only two places oneTime was declared as a global variable and where I changed it. I did this to try and test why it was not working in the first place and when I saw it being true in the console and never turn false, I was totally confused.